# ARM cortex a7 - VLDR instruction

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-a

[ARM cortex A7].

I wonder if it is better to `pop`/`push` registers instead of **temporarily** moving them in neon vectors.

No official timings are there to help choose the strategy.

Do someone know if `VLDR`/`VSTR` combo is faster than a **hot** `push`/`pop`?

Thanks

Comment: IDK if it matters on that specific uarch, but is your loop latency-sensitive , or will you still bottleneck on throughput if the save/restore round trip has high latency?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't change much, the real problem is retrieving from neon to a register (quite slow). So, on this arch, I will stick to the simplest plan. Thanks Peter